# Changing Weathertron to Honeywell Thermostat

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I have a GE Weathertron (model 3AAT80 1A1/2A1) that I want to switch over to a Honeywell (RTH6360).  Most of the wiring seems straight forward, but ...

R (Weathertron) to R (Honeywell)

O               to O/B

G               to G

Y               to Y

B               to ? (i believe C)

T               to ?

... and do I need to jump U and W on the Honeywell like the Weathertron does?

Any thoughts are super welcome.

Bolko

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good for you. You took pictures before taking everything apart. Do the instructions provide a diagram?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler/furnace, and a wiring diagram for that unit for that matter please?

Comment: To Jack and ThreePhaseEel:  1.  Instructions do have a diagram, but it is unclear about B (Weathertron) to C (Honeywell).  Also, there is no mention of a T wire and if U needs to be jumped to W.   2.  I will add a picture of the the wiring in the wall closest to the air-handler.  Looks like spaghetti to me, but hopefully someone can make sense of it.  The air-handler is a 1980's GE model and I have not been able to find a wiring diagram.

Comment: @Bolko -- the wiring shot you posted appears to be of mains wiring inside a box in the wall, not the thermostat wiring, which will be inside the air handler's own wiring/blower compartment

Comment: Yes, you are correct the wiring is outside of the air handler.  Found schematic (picture added).  There is no easy access to view the wiring in the unit.  Would require to completely take front and/or side panels off.  Hoping that i do not have to do that and that the schematic will work.  Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Bolko -- sadly, you'll have to pull the access panel off the air handler to do this